# JMeter how to insert value into dynamic table

Tags: jmeter

With JMeter I simulate different user login into application, and each user have table with different number of column. I want to put value into table which sum will be equal to 1. If rowcount is 3 I must put 1/3 triple in each column. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to do, but if you need to do math, use a jexl command.  It will take variables, so you could do ${__jexl(${login} / 3}

See the Jmeter manual.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html